# Entering Strings of Bytes into C Program User Input

Tags: python, c, linux, input, user-input

I'm working on a problem which involves performing a buffer overflow on a C program. The program asks for a command line input from the user, and I need to use this input to enter in my byte string including nops, shellcode, ret address, etc. The problem is the c program interprets everything I enter as a literal string, so if I enter in something like "\xff\xab\x12..." the program will interpret each separate character as a different byte. I can enter in separate bytes by creating a string of the corresponding ASCII characters for each byte, but this limits me to hex values 00-7F for my byte values. I'm wondering if there's some way I can use python to enter in the byte string, or possibly format the user input so that the C program interprets it the way I need it to. Please note that I don't know what the return address of the byte string will be until after I start running the program, so I can't make the byte string prior to running the C program I'm working on a Linux x86 shell, and I do not have the source code for the C program.

I've tried calling python to print the string I need into the input using commands like,

```
$(python -c 'print "\x41" * 205 + "\x34\x86")
```

but the C program just interprets all these characters literally. I've also tried using extended ASCII characters but the C program doesn't seem to interpret them correctly, associating them all with an unknown character symbol and 0xc3 hex value. Is it possible there is some other character/hex mapping that the C program may be using?

If anyone knows a way I can enter the input the way I need to, your help would be very much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "*interprets all these characters literally*"?

Comment: What shell are you using?

Comment: Please start with a [mcve]. Your current question contains to many guesses and interpretations and too little facts. The MCVE makes sure you have a reproducible recipe that everyone here can use. Also, make sure you took the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: By "interprets all these characters literally," I mean that the C program thinks I just entered the character string "$(python -c 'print "\x41" * 205 + "\x34\x86")." I'm using a bash shell.

Comment: How are you passing input to your C program? STDIN or via an argument?

Comment: @bool3max, It's via STDIN.

Comment: @Jdeloz828 Then use the 2nd form described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a semicolon (`'`) in your shell call to `python`. Additionally:

If your executable takes its input in the form of a CLI argument:

`$ ./yourprog $(python -c 'print "\x41" * 205 + "\x34\x86"')`

---

If it takes its input in the form of STDIN:

`$ python -c 'print "\x41" * 205 + "\x34\x86"' | ./yourprog`

---

Replace `"./yourprog"` with the name of your executable.

Comment: I tried it. The program still interprets the string literally. It takes each char in the string "$ python -c 'print "\x41" * 205 + "\x34\x86"' | ./yourprog" and enters in the bytes of the buffer as the hex value of "$", " ", "p", "y", "t", etc...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. You need to show the sourcecode of your program.