# Handing bytes as command line argument to program

Tags: c

I am trying to exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability. To do so, I want to pass an address that was previously determined (such as `\x00\x00\x41\xab\x00\xab`) to a program such that it will be written to the memory as bytes, not the byte representation of the input string. Consider the example:

```
Address I want to write as hex string: \x00\x00\x41\xab\x00\xab 

Memory before overflow: ab ab 00 00 aa 00  (these values could be arbitrary since its stack memory) 
Memory after overflow : 00 00 41 ab 00 ab
```

The buffer I am trying to write to is accesses in the following way:

```
void overflow(char input[], end){
    for(int a = 0; a < end; ++a){
        char buffer[32];
        buffer[a] = input[a];
}
```

The value of `end` is determined by the length of `input`. The overflow is irrelevant for my question. What I am asking is:

How can I pass an address in whatever representation (hex, bytestring, etc.) to the program as a command line argument (via `argv[]`), such that it is written to memory as shown above?

Especially, how do I deal with `\x00` characters?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56315348/entering-strings-of-bytes-into-c-program-user-input) question, which unfortunately didn't provide a solution. Note that I am not trying to pipe the parameters, since the program does not read from stdin.

Comment: IMO the simple way is to pass a text string like "000041ab00ab" and then convert it to the corresponding values

Comment: I believe this is not possible, since elements in `argv` are expected to be NUL terminated

Comment: I did  not get how exactly the commandline for calling the prgram with the desired address would look like. Please give an example. If it is not defined and you are only asking how to represent an address as a argv argument to the program please say that more explicitly. I think that is however much simpler, almost so simple that I do not get what your question is.

Comment: ./program input, the input would hereby be the address in whatever format needed to achieve what I am trying to do

Comment: You can read the data from `stdin`, and when invoking redirect either from a binary file of from python or similar such as `python -c 'print ("\x12\x34")' | ./your_program`. You just need to use input functions that are not string-centric.

Comment: @EugeneSh. "Note that I am not trying to pipe the parameters, since the program does not read from stdin."

Comment: Some consoles/terminals allow you to pass on raw binary to an executable. Or you can do so from another program launching the one with command-line arguments.

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh well, that's an omission... in that case there are techniques for null-free exploitations, but it is beyond the scope of the question

Comment: So `./program "0x00 0x00 0x41 0xab 0x00 0xab"` would be a syntax you could use? Or  `./program 0x00 0x00 0x41 0xab 0x00 0xab`?

Comment: The input is one argument, not multiple arguments

Comment: So `./program "0x00 0x00 0x41 0xab 0x00 0xab"` would be a syntax you could use?

Comment: How much experience do you have with using argv? Can you show an [mre] of your best attempt? Maybe reading in any argument and just echoing it?

Comment: I think the idea here is to craft the exploit in such a way, that the return address you are trying to overwrite *won't* contain any zeros, and then you can provide it in `argv`.

Comment: In Linux, you are ultimately calling the `execve` or `execveat` syscall which expects a NULL terminated array of pointers to null terminated strings. If you embed a zero byte in an argument, the argument will be truncated at that point. The bytes after the zero byte will not appear in the argument block of the replacement process image.

Comment: Anyway, because of ASLR, is learning how to do this at all relevant in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I would take the input as a text string like "000041ab00ab" and then write some simple code to do the conversion.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

unsigned char conv_char(char c)
{
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            return c - '0';
        }
        
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
        {
            return c - 'a' + 10;
        }
        
        exit(1);
}

void get_values(const char* str, unsigned char* values)
{
    if (strlen(str) != 12) exit(1);
    for (int i=0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        values[i] = conv_char(str[2*i]);
        values[i] = values[i] << 4;
        values[i] = values[i] | conv_char(str[2*i + 1]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    if (argc != 2) exit(1);
    unsigned char values[6];
    get_values(argv[1], values);
    
    for (int i=0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        printf("0x%02x ", values[i]);
    }    
    puts("");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Running this as `prog 000041ab00ab` gives the output:

```
0x00 0x00 0x41 0xab 0x00 0xab
```

Comment: Are you suggesting modifying a vulnerable program to make it more vulnerable? Hm.. doesn't sound like something that the OP at least should be asking about TBH...